# What is the proper way to link big template assets into rails erb files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, assets

I am developing a rails application starting from [webarch template](http://themeforest.net/item/webarch-responsive-admin-dashboard-template/full_screen_preview/6157416). I know that adding the whole assets folder in the public/ folder will link the assets with my views, but it would not be taking advantage of the assets pipeline functions. The template has a lot of plugins and different options and one generally does not use all of it. The assets folder's size is 30MB.

I though about putting it inside vendor/assets and using it with the asset pipeline but this generates two problems:

1. I would be serving 30MB of minified code and using a small percentage of it in my app.
2. I would have to manually rewrite the whole assets folder to use links the way asset pipeline wants it (`javascript_include_tag "file"` to serve file.js). Of course, I would do this via a script but it still seems like a problem someone should have encountered first.

Since neither vendor/assets and public/ folders seem to be a proper location for these files I would like a better option (or a way to make the later options work better).

Comment: Proper solution is simply to not put in 30MB of unused assets into your project. Normally templates have a small core (which is OK to include in assets) and the rest of components are optional. Cherry-picking / adapting these files takes time, but it's worth the effort.

Comment: @vemv I see often this kind of comment on SO, and sorry if I react on yours. This is not a proper thing to say. I mean you can say it, but go ahead and deliver a solution, or else just say nothing. You see, there is not one single way of coding, nor one single type of situation, and sometimes you end-up obliged to do thing that you would normally avoid doing. SO is here to provide help, not school kind of lectures. Cheers

Comment: @BenjaminSinclaire what? I gave a specific, applicable advise which tends to be correct for many kind of projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution to keep your files under asset pipeline when they are too big to reasonably be left in one single minimified asset file is to split your assets by categories, compile those categories in different minimified files, and include them in your views when needed.

I do it for an app that contains several "heavy" javascripts components that are located in different area of my app and are not often used.

**1-** Organize your file structure

In *app/assets/javascrips* and *app/assets/stylesheets* create one directory per category we are going to create. Examples:

- app/assets/javascrips/common
- app/assets/javascrips/admin
- app/assets/javascrips/user_account

**2-** Create your manifests

In *app/assets/javascrips* and *app/assets/stylesheets* create one manifest file per category and have them included the related directory

File *app/assets/javascrips/common.js*

```
//= require jquery
//= require_tree ./common
```

File *app/assets/javascrips/admin.js*

```
//= require_tree ./admin
```

File *app/assets/javascrips/user_account.js*

```
//= require_tree ./user_account
```

**3-** Add your manifests to rails *precompile* list

You can do it in *config/application.rb* file, but when it gets big it is preferable to create an initializer file *config/initializers/assets.rb*

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.assets.precompile += %w[common.js admin.js user_account.js]
end
```

**4-** Include them in your views and layouts, and set-up your javascript libraries.

Import the assets files into layouts and views. It can be a good idea to create several layouts for different area of your application that would be using common assets files. The methods to use are 
`stylesheet_link_tag 'manifest_file'` and `javascript_include_tag 'manifest_file'`

And keep in mind you may have to tell your javascript plug-ins they need to use the miniminied file when dynamically loading files. For them you can use a configuration *.js.erb* file. Example:

File *app/assets/javascrips/admin/plug-in_config.js.erb*

```
PLUGIN.config('dynamicFileName', '<%= javascript_path('manifest_file') %>');
```